# How to access saved data from different method?

Tags: java, android, string, methods, save

I am trying to save a value as a string on the device's internal memory so that it can be accessed when the app is closed and reopened by clicking another button. When I run the program, I enter values for inputs A and B, and I know it processes them through the calculations because I modified it so that it displays the answer as soon as it is calculated.
But on this version, if I click the save button, and subsequently click the Access button to show the answer and the textview labeled Previous Answer, it simply shows "xx" which is the initial value of the string I'm trying to save. So either it doesnt store the updated version which includes the answer, or the Access button is only able to access the original value of the string.

```
    Button jSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.iSave);
    Button jAccess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.iAccess);



    final String saveName="Name";
    final String saveValue = "xx";




    jSave.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){


                //Calculations. These are a part of a more complex series of 
                //calculations between several classes, but I've simplified it
                //somewhat for this post.
                EditText jInputA = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.iInputA);
                double dInputA = Double.parseDouble(jInputA.getText().toString());
                EditText jInputB = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.iInputB);
                double dInputB = Double.parseDouble(jInputB.getText().toString());
                double myAnswer = Double.parseDouble(ProfileCalculations.functionQ(jInputA, jInputB));


                //Update the value of saveValue to match that of myAnswer
                final String saveValue = "The answer is " myAnswer;


                //Save saveValue as a string under file saveName
                try{
                  FileOutputStream jFOS = openFileOutput(saveName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                  jFOS.write(saveValue.getBytes());
                  jFOS.close();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                  Logger.getLogger(Profile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                  Logger.getLogger(Profile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }



                }
            }

    );



    jAccess.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   try {
                       FileInputStream jFIS = openFileInput(saveName);
                       jFIS.read(saveValue.getBytes());
                       jFIS.close();
                   } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                       Logger.getLogger(Profile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                   } catch (IOException ex) {
                       Logger.getLogger(Profile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                   }

                    TextView jPreviousAns = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.iPreviousAns);
                    jPreviousAns.setText(saveValue + "");
                }
            }

    );
```

Comment: Not sure, as to your file handling... I'm too new. But, why are you not using shared preferences? This seems to be a textbook case for their use.

Answer (score 0):

How about shared preferences? Here's an example.

```
private SharedPreferences defaultPrefs;
defaultPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

String url = "http://www.example.com";
SharedPreferences.Editor ed = defaultPrefs.edit();
ed.putString("homepage", url);
ed.commit();
```

And, later:

```
String url = defaultPrefs.getString("homepage", "http://www.example.com/some_default_page");
```

Answer (score 0):

Android provides several options for you to save persistent application data. The solution you choose depends on your specific needs, such as whether the data should be private to your application or accessible to other applications (and the user) and how much space your data requires.

Your data storage options are the following:

**Shared Preferences**
Store private primitive data in key-value pairs.

**Internal Storage**
Store private data on the device memory.

**External Storage**
Store public data on the shared external storage.

**SQLite Databases**
Store structured data in a private database.

**Network Connection**
Store data on the web with your own network server.

For your given application of this, I would imagine that *Shared Preferences* or *Internal Storage* would be the way to go.

**Internal Storage:** Using this route, you would have to call *openFileOutput()* to start a *FileOutputStream*, and from there use *write()* to write data to the file, and *close()* to close the *FileOutputStream*.

Ex:

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

//Initiate
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//Write to file
fos.write(string.getBytes());

//Close file
fos.close();
```

**Shared Preferences:** If you are to use this, then you must call *edit()* to get a *SharedPrefrencesEditor*,  and then to add values to this, you would simply use *putBoolean()*, *putString()*, etc. Once you're finished you commit the data using *commit()*.

Ex:

```
//Initiate Shared Preferences
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

//Writes data
editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);

// Commit the edits!
editor.commit();
```

[(Source)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)